# Get Client Value Back from ASP.Net Custom Control

Tags: asp.net, svg, custom-controls, request.form

I'm having issues getting a control to pass its value back to my server from the browser. Essentially, what I need is a LiteralControl that can be pushed onto the page, modified by some JavaScript, and then pass its entire contents back.

What I'm doing: I'm working with an SVG image. I need to send whatever pre-initialized value (display elements/content) to the browser. Then the user can interact with the image via JavaScript. Whenever they submit the form, I need to get the new/modified image back.

I made a custom control that outputs the SVG element, and allows you to set custom width, height, and viewbox attributes. It has a style element that you can provide content for, and a script element that you can also provide some content for. I've set up a ScriptDescriptor for all the properties that should be modified on the browser. I built an SvgImage.prototype and an SvgImage.descriptors JavaScript class, and registered my namespace and class in JavaScript. My JavaScript is all making it to the browser, but the control isn't added to the Request.Form elements coming back in.

Is there any way to get the control added to the Request.Form elements without creating a hidden field and dumping the content into it?

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do this *without* using some sort of input control, as those are the only things that will be posted back to the sever as part of the form. Even using `asp:Label` wouldn't work, because any client side changes would not be returned

Comment: I'm a little worried about that, but I want to KNOW it can't be done before I go that route.

Comment: Did you manage to find anything? I've had a look around (now that I'm at my development machine, which I wasn't when I wrote my earlier comment), can't find anything obvious, and as you have a lack of responses I would guess there isn't anything native to ASP.NET to do this. So looks like you will have to bite the bullet and write something using a control that can actually post-back to the server... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in my comment, I am unaware of any native ASP.NET control that would allow you to do this.

All form information posted back to the server has to be (to my knowledge) contained within an `<input>` control.  (As I'm sure you're aware, ASP.NET can only work with standard form processing as supplied by your average browser.)

So I think you're looking at transfering the SVG information into a hidden control (an invisible `<textarea>` / `<asp:TextBox TextMode="Multiline"/>` makes most sense) before the post-back takes place.

Another option could be to use AJAX, although if you only want the the information at the point of post-back, you could run into trouble with the timing of it... so I can't see it being much use (but just mentioning it as an option).

Comment: I've started working toward using a hidden field with the values in it to take care of the data transfer. I'll leave the question open for a couple days to see if I can get something else that will work in the mean time. Thanks!